# Command based Java: Accessing a method from a subsystem in a command (Java)

Tags: java, methods, command, subsystem

this is my first time using Java and I seem to be stuck. I'm trying to access a method (getHeading) from a subsystem (DriveTrain) in a command (DriveStraight), but I keep getting the error that "the type getHeading(double) is undefined for the type Subsystem" when I try `heading = Robot.DriveTrain.getHeading();`. This is the command:

```
public class DriveStraight extends Command {

    private double speed;
    private double duration;
    private double heading;

    public DriveStraight(float driveSpeed, float duration) {
        requires(Robot.DriveTrain);
        **heading = Robot.DriveTrain.getHeading();**
    }

    // Called just before this Command runs the first time
    protected void initialize() {
        setTimeout(duration);
    }

    // Called repeatedly when this Command is scheduled to run
    protected void execute() {
        **float currentheading = Robot.DriveTrain.getHeading();**
        Robot.DriveTrain.arcadeDrive(speed, (heading - currentheading) * 0.08);
    }
```

And this is the subsystem:

```
public class DriveTrain extends Subsystem {
    AnalogGyro gyro;

    RobotDrive drive;
    VictorSP frontLeftMotor, rearLeftMotor, frontRightMotor, rearRightMotor;

    public DriveTrain() {
        frontLeftMotor = new VictorSP(RobotMap.frontLeftMotor);
        rearLeftMotor = new VictorSP(RobotMap.rearLeftMotor);
        frontRightMotor = new VictorSP(RobotMap.frontRightMotor);
        rearRightMotor = new VictorSP(RobotMap.rearRightMotor);

        gyro = new AnalogGyro(RobotMap.analogGyro);
        gyro.setSensitivity(0.00666);
        gyro.calibrate();
    }

    public void arcadeDrive(float speed, float turn) {
        drive.arcadeDrive(OI.joy.getRawAxis(OI.LEFT_Y_AXIS),
                OI.joy.getRawAxis(OI.RIGHT_X_AXIS), true);
    }

    public void tankDrive(float leftValue, float rightValue) {
        drive.tankDrive(OI.joy.getRawAxis(OI.LEFT_Y_AXIS),
                OI.joy.getRawAxis(OI.RIGHT_Y_AXIS), true);
    }

    public double getHeading() {
        return gyro.getAngle();
    }

    protected void initDefaultCommand() {
        arcadeDrive(0, 0);
    }   
}
```

I just came from using C++ so I think I might be trying to use pointers, but I'm not sure. So what's the right way to call a method from a subsystem?

Thanks,
Sethra53

Comment: try like this `DriveTrain ob = new DriveTrain();double currentheading = ob.getHeading();`

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not managing an instance of Robot.DriveTrain anywhere - all your method calls on the DriveTrain class are being seen by the compiler as calls to `static` methods (which don't relate to an object, only to the class). The nearest matching method you have defined anywhere is `public double getHeading() {`, which is an instance method and so should be called on an instance. There are 4 places in your code which are referring to `Robot.DriveTrain` and I'm not sure what your `requires` method is doing so it's tricky to know what you should be passing to it. The other three places, however, should be referring to instances of `Robot.DriveTrain`.

e.g.

```
public class DriveStraight extends Command {

    private double speed;
    private double duration;
    private double heading;
    private Robot.DriveTrain driveTrain;

    public DriveStraight(float driveSpeed, float duration) {
        requires(Robot.DriveTrain);
        driveTrain = new Robot.DriveTrain()            // create new shared instance
        heading = driveTrain.getHeading();             // use instance.
    }

    // Called just before this Command runs the first time
    protected void initialize() {
        setTimeout(duration);
    }

    // Called repeatedly when this Command is scheduled to run
    protected void execute() {
        float currentheading = driveTrain.getHeading();    // use instance created in constructor.
        driveTrain.arcadeDrive(speed, (heading - currentheading) * 0.08);
    }
    ...
```

I can't guarantee any of that will 'work' however, without understanding how the `requires` method call works.

A better approach would be to pass the instance in to the `DriveStraight` constructor...

```
public class DriveStraight extends Command {
    private Robot.DriveTrain driveTrain;

    public DriveStraight(float driveSpeed, float duration, DriveTrain driveTrain) {
        this.driveTrain = driveTrain; // use instance created elsewhere
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out the constructor for the subsystem in Robot.java was declared improperly. Now the commands can access the subsystems just fine.